# Separation of Variables using Complex Fourier Series

Tags: partial-differential-equations, solution-verification, circles, fourier-series, harmonic-functions

I am trying to solve a PDE by applying separation of variables using the complex form of a Fourier Series.  The PDE to solve is $$\bigtriangleup u = 0,\ u(1,\ \theta) = 2\pi\theta - \theta^2$$

I plugged $u = R(r)T(\theta)$ into the polar Laplacian formula, and ended up with $\frac{T_{\theta \theta}}{T} = \lambda$ and $-\frac{r^2 R_{rr} + r R_r}{R} = \lambda$.  My solutions to the Sturm-Liouville problems are $R = Ar^{-\sqrt{-\lambda}} + Br^{\sqrt{-\lambda}}$ and $T = Ce^{-\sqrt\lambda \theta} + De^{\sqrt\lambda \theta}$ (I have ruled out the $\lambda = 0$ case).  Thus I have $$u = (Ar^{-\sqrt{-\lambda}} + Br^{\sqrt{-\lambda}})(Ce^{-\sqrt\lambda \theta} + De^{\sqrt\lambda \theta})$$

Since the given boundary condition implies that the domain is a disk, I also have the implied boundary conditions $u(r,\ 0) = u(r,\ 2\pi)$ and $u_\theta (r,\ 0) = u_\theta (r,\ 2\pi)$.  Plugging these implied conditions into the general solution yields an algebraic system with solution $\lambda = -n^2$, where $n$ is an arbitrary integer, therefore $$u = \sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty (A_n r^{-n} + B_n r^n)(C_n e^{-n \theta i} + D_n e^{n \theta i})$$

Now I think the RHS expression here has a redundancy which allows me to kill $C_n e^{-n \theta i}$ without losing any of the correct terms, because of the two-sided summation.  Then I can lump $D_n$ into $A_n$ and $B_n$ simplifying things to $$u = \sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty (A_n r^{-n} + B_n r^n)e^{n \theta i}$$

Applying the given boundary condition yields $2\pi\theta - \theta^2 = \sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty (A_n + B_n)e^{n \theta i}$.  The Fourier coefficient $A_n + B_n$ should be given by $\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} (2\pi\theta - \theta^2)e^{-n\theta i} d\theta$, which is $-\frac{2}{n^2}$.  This leads to $u = \sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty (A_n r^{-n} + (-\frac{2}{n^2} - A_n)r^n)e^{n \theta i}$, which expands to $$u = \sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty \frac{(A_n n^2 r^{-n} - A_n n^2 r^n - 2r^n)(cos(n\theta) + sin(n\theta)i)}{n^2}$$

I think this answer is incorrect, because if we consider the special case of the problem which models an equilibrium temperature distribution, then $A_n$ must be $0$ (because $u$ must be finite at the origin), and $u$ must be real, but in my answer $u$ is not in fact real when $A_n = 0$.  What am I doing incorrectly to arrive at this solution?

Comment: I suspect you want to integrate on $[0, 2\pi]$ rather than $[-\pi,\pi]$, because the function $u(1,\theta)$ is discontinuous on the former interval and continuous on the latter interval.  If it's the former case, the expansion coefficient $A_n+B_n$ is real, and so when you add the $n$ and $-n$ terms, you get something real. If it's the latter case (as in the OP), I think that if you add the $n$ to the $-n$ terms, you still get something that's real.

Comment: Google "Poisson Kernel"... it solves this problem instantly.

Comment: @march I have written two new questions to try to go further into these two suggestions.

Comment: @K.defaoite I am more interested in learning to apply separation of variables using Complex Fourier Series and ending with a real answer than I am actually knowing the solution.

Comment: After looking at the other questions, it really does seem like the problem statement is not complete. First of all, there should be some boundary conditions on $r$, since it's not enough to specify the value of the function on the circle.  You also need some sort of regularity conditions at either $r=0$ or $r\to\infty$.  Typically, the condition is that the function is finite at $r=0$ or zero at $r\to\infty$. These conditions pick out one or the other of the $r^k$ terms.

Comment: Next, the function on the circle clearly depends on the choice of interval. Yes, the function is defined on the circle, but in the implementation, you are specifying a function that isn't "naturally" periodic on the circle, and so you have to specify "what piece" of that function actually lives on the circle. On the face of it, there's nothing *wrong* with the function being discontinuous (as long as it's bounded and the number of discontinuities is finite), but for typical *physical* contexts, the function is continuous.

Comment: Finally (and sorry to fill up the comments here), my original guess that the imaginary piece should go to zero is likely not correct. There's no reason *a priori* that the solution has to be real.  That's part of the specification of the problem that includes the boundary conditions.  I'll try to write up as much as I know about this problem at some point, but for now, it's worth thinking about these things!

Comment: @march I think the first regularity condition you describe is what I mentioned in the question when I considered setting $A_n$ to $0$ in the final solution?  Some might take action earlier within the solution process, whereas I think my approach reveals the more complete solution first and imposes the requirement of regularity at the end, which seems more insightful.  With that said, if the solution is supposed to be real, then $A_n = 0$ might not work, and I might have to pick the $A_n$'s in such a way that cancels the imaginary part of the solution?

Comment: @march I have updated the question to integrate over the correct interval, as you suggested.  I have also indicated why I think the imaginary part of my new solution is still a problem.

Comment: At $r=1$, $u(\theta) = ^{-\sqrt{}}+^{\sqrt{}}$. As $u(0) = 0$, $C = -D$.

Comment: @player100 Can you explain this in more words?  Maybe I am missing something obvious, but I can't see how evaluating $u(1,\ 0)$ allows a general conclusion about the relation between $C$ and $D$.

Comment: Because the coefficients must satisfy the boundary conditions. When you “killed” the C coefficient you created solutions that were imaginary. Yet your boundary condition is real.  In any case, it isn’t necessary to use complex exponentials as your ansatz. Why not try $\sin$ and $\cos$? I think from there it is easy to see that only certain modes work.

Comment: @player100 Interesting, I will have to think on killing $C$ creating the imaginary solutions.  As for the second part, I have solved PDEs using real Fourier Series.  I had heard many people sing the praises of using complex Fourier Series to solve PDEs, so I wanted to give it a try.  My book does not actually use complex Fourier Series in any PDE examples, and although I found a few videos online, they tend to either leave the answer in complex form, use trivial initial conditions, or otherwise explain things in a way I can't apply directly.