# How can I solve this two-sided infinite summation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, partial-differential-equations, complex-numbers, summation, infinity

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4249567/separation-of-variables-using-complex-fourier-series) question, the comment suggests that the imaginary terms in the stated solution might sum to $0$.  In order for this to happen, it must be the case that

$\sum_{-\infty}^\infty [\frac{2(-1)^{n + 1} r^n \sin(n\theta) + 2(-1)^n n\pi r^n \cos(n\theta)}{n^2} + Im(\frac{A_n n^2 r^{-n} \cos(n\theta) - A_n n^2 r^n \cos(n\theta) + A_n n^2 r^{-n} \sin(n\theta)i - A_n n^2 r^n \sin(n\theta)i}{n^2})i] = 0$

This should hold for all real numbers $r$ and $\theta$, but if it does not hold for all $A_n$ (which can be complex), finding the $A_n$'s where it does work could help narrow down the solution.  It should at least hold for $A_n = 0$ if the PDE solution is to have a physical interpretation of equilibrium temperature.

I recall from solving ODEs via power series that it is often legal to drop a summation operator in an equation like this and assume that each term must equal $0$ in and of itself, but I am not sure if this works with the complex numbers here, nor the two-sided infinite summation.  I also do not know how to deal with the imaginary part operator which emerges due to the uncertainty of whether the $A_n$'s are real or imaginary.

How can I see if this equation if true, or if not, for which value of $A_n$ it is true?

Comment: The reason why you're allowed to set each term to zero when solving an ODE using the power series method is because $0=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n\Longrightarrow a_n=0$, by a theorem of complex analysis. Here, if you can write the summation as a sum over linearly independent functions, then, under proper assumptions about how the coefficients behave with $n$, you also are forced to conclude that the coefficients are zero. However, setting this equal to zero *a priori* comes from the specification of the problem (which *could* be, "I'm looking for real solutions).

Comment: @march So when a linear PDE (even a "real-looking" one, with no $i$'s floating around the PDE or given conditions) is solved by separation of variables using real Fourier Series (sines and cosines), are there often a bunch of non-real solutions, such as the solutions I found using complex Fourier Series, being discarded silently?

Comment: That happens even in finite dimensions. You can solve for the general positions of two coupled oscillators (which can be written as two coupled, 2nd-order, homogeneous, linear differential equations, which can then solved in terms of a "Fourier series"), and in general, the solutions can be complex.  Only after we apply physically realizable initial conditions do we get a necessarily real solution.