# How Can I Visualize a PDE Boundary Condition?

Tags: geometry, partial-differential-equations, graphing-functions, polar-coordinates, mathematica

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4249567/separation-of-variables-using-complex-fourier-series) question, the comment suggests that the integration bounds in the Fourier Series should be chosen to avoid discontinuities in the boundary conditions.  I am trying to produce a nice visual to see this sort of discontinuity.

The visual I have in mind is a curve in 3-dimensional space, which lives somewhere within the infinite cylinder $r = 1$.  I want to know if there is an easy way to draw this, i.e., in Mathematica.

As a workaround, I created a 2-dimensional graph in Desmos...

[image]

1. I assume the way to determine from a 2-dimension graph like this that the boundary condition is continuous from $0$ to $2\pi$ is to note that the green line is continuous and that its endpoints are the same.  By contrast, the red line is also continuous, but its endpoints are not the same, so the boundary condition is not continuous from $-\pi$ to $\pi$.  This is based on the idea of wrapping each of these intervals around the cylinder.  Is this approach on point?
2. How can I actually graph the 3-dimensional boundary condition without knowing the solution to the PDE in Mathematica, MATLAB, or some online graphing tool?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you want. Do you want to just wrap the plot of the boundary condition around the surface of a cylinder? I can show you how to do that, but not here. Mathematica SE or Stack Overflow would be a better place for that kind of question.

Comment: @K.defaoite Yeah, I think that would be the right way to visualize a boundary condition when the $x$ and $y$ axes are the PDE inputs and the vertical axis is the unknown function.  If the bounty expires without a good answer being given, I will ask this part of the question on Mathematica SE.

Comment: Regarding the original question that you linked to, I don't think that *you* are supposed to pick one interpretation or the other. Surely whoever gave you the problem had in mind some particular *context* where it was *understood* that the polar coordinate $\theta$ should be taken in the interval $0 \le \pi < 2\pi$. Without such a context, the problem is not well-defined, since it's not clear what $u$ is actually supposed to equal on the boundary.

Comment: @HansLundmark You are correct.  The interval was given by the original problem statement.  I simply didn't copy it because it felt like fluff at the time, but now I see the significance.  I have removed this part of the question.

Comment: And for this question here, can't you just use [ParametricPlot3D](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot3D.html) in Mathematica?

Comment: @K.defaoite In case you are interested, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/256175/how-can-i-visualize-a-pde-boundary-condition